# Найти значение в массиве (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется колонка `Col_name` с типом `json` в которой хранятся значения в виде:

```
| Id          | Col_name           |
| ----------- | ------------------ |
| 1           | ["home"]           |
| 2           | ["work"]           |
| 3           | ["home","work"]    |
```

Я хочу выбрать все строки у которых есть в массиве `"home"`, т.е. 1-я и 3-я строка. Я почитал и в документации пишут, массив должен быть вида `{"home", "work"}` и тогда можно будет найти по запросу:

```sql
    SELECT Col_name
    FROM Table 
    WHERE Col_name::varchar = ANY('{home}')
```

Но у меня хранится массив в другом виде, подскажите как можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз у вас тип поля json - то и [операторы](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) нужно смотреть для json.

Вам нужно изменить тип данных этого поля на `jsonb` и тогда сможете использовать соответствующие операторы, в частности:

```
where col_name ? 'home'
```

Comment: `WHERE Col_name::jsonb ? 'home' `, да, вот так с приведением типа к jsonb работает, спасибо!